# How do I say “here” in time?

Tags: expressions, time

> I am here.

conveys spatial information.

How would I say the same about temporal information?

Say I were a time traveller, and to specify that someone/something is not “here” - in time.

Comment: "I am" does it pretty well.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About single word requests

Comment: I'm sure a time traveller would be quite happy to say things like *Here I am in the fifteenth century,* where ***here*** would be both intended and understood as a *temporal* (not spatial) reference.

Comment: A word I've seen used (and use often myself) for the _opposite_ of _now_ is ***elsewhen*** (the temporal equivalent of elsewhere).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The temporal equivalent to the spatial *here* is *now*.

> **now** *adverb*
>   At the present time or moment.
>   ‘where are you living now?’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/now)

Your sample sentence would look like this:

- Someone / something is not here *now*.

Comment: the ODO says it well: ... _present_ **time** ..., so _present_ is it.

Comment: @HongboZhu You can also have the present *location*. It does convey something similar to 'now', but I think "now" is a better temporal analogue (than "present") to "here". One might even argue that *current/present* is another form of *now/here* as a *temporal/spatial* pair.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with both the spatial ‘here’ and the temporal ‘now’ is that both are relative.

If I write you a letter with no address of sender or date, saying “Dear Julia, I am here now.  Best wishes, Fred”, and send it, I shall have written the truth, but you will be none the wiser as to my precise location or the time of writing.

So the most common use for ‘here’ and ‘now’ involves three or more individuals:  The speaker, the Audience and one or more people/thing spoken about.

> He/they are here now

This works because both speaker and audience know where ‘here’ is and when ‘now’ is.

This is at the root of a powerful - I would say irresistible - argument that time travel is not just physically but also logically impossible.  For any speaker, ‘now’ and ‘then’ cannot (by definition) be simultaneous.  It can never be both now and not now at the same time.

Time travel can work in fiction if we make a “willing suspension of disbelief.”.  We read (or see) that the hero or villain disappears in a puff of smoke.  So for the time of origin s/he is no longer here now but here then.  And next we are presented the same location as a ne here now (but really here then), looking quite different as hero/villain reappears in a puff of smoke.  But from that moment, everything the time traveller into the past (say the exterminator) has left a record of his doings, including the robot crushed in the steam hammer, and the wreckage everywhere.  There would be police investigations and newspaper headlines.  So when 
model 2 exterminator shows up, and even more when model three shows up, the world would be more informed.  But the movie is good enough so that we do not spend our time thinking it out.

Answer (score 1):

**at this moment in time**

> At the present moment; right now; currently. [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+this+moment+in+time) idiom

As in:

> At this moment in time , I am X.